What is the equivalent of Android's `consumePurchase` in iOS?
I use this function to consume a purchase in Android. This function allows the user to re-purchase again a Non-consumable. It works fine. What is its equivalent in iOS ?
  Future<void> consumePurchaseAndroid(PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
    print("Consuming Purchase: $purchaseDetails");
    final androidAddition = _inAppPurchase
        .getPlatformAddition<InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition>();
    await androidAddition.consumePurchase(purchaseDetails);
    print("Consumed: ${purchaseDetails.productID}");
    return;
  }

iOS
 Future<void> consumePurchaseIOS(PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
    print("Consuming Purchase: $purchaseDetails");
    // Update UI or unlock content
    final iosAddition  = _inAppPurchase
        .getPlatformAddition<InAppPurchaseStoreKitPlatformAddition>();
    // await androidAddition.consumePurchase(purchaseDetails);
    // ???
    return;
  }

Note: This is for testing purpose

You can't consume non-consumable purchases on iOS.  You can use transaction manager in Xcode to delete a previous purchase for testing.  There is also a test framework for use in automated testing
